# How to remove the unspecified space between root and include url in django 2.2

Tags: django, url

I am trying to create a Django website. I have specified the path to one of my apps. But I am getting an unspecified space in the pattern.I am using Django 2.2. [screenshot of the django debug page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoLnh.png)

my base urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('homepage.urls')),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('db/', include('dashboard.urls')),

]
```

my dashboard/urls.py file

```
from django.urls import include, path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    #author dashboard
    path('authordboard/<int:auth_id/',views.author_dboard, name='author_details'),
    #reviewer dashboard
    path('reviewdboard/<int:re_id/',views.re_dboard, name='reviewer_details'),

]
```

I have included the dashboard app in the settings.py file.
Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

you must close variable declared in url. in your dashboard/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    #author dashboard
    path('authordboard/<int:auth_id>/',views.author_dboard, name='author_details'),
    #reviewer dashboard
    path('reviewdboard/<int:re_id>/',views.re_dboard, name='reviewer_details'),
]
```